# Set order of columns in DynamoDB table of AWS

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, datatable, amazon-dynamodb

I'm newbie on **Amazon web services** cloud. I'm trying to store my data to aws **DynamoDB** table. I have created table into **DynamoDB** using **python script**. Please show below snapshot.

[image: aws]

In the table, **order of columns** doesn't showing according to my requirements. I want to order of columns something like,

```
Rpi_ID    RowKey    Name         Time            Date

A100       1        msc       02:07:18 PM       01-04-2017
```

So, **how to set columns according to my requirements?**

my pythons **put item** code:

```
Table.put_item(
           Item={
            'RowKey': 1,            
            'Rpi_ID': 'A100',
            'Name': 'msc',
            'Time': time.strftime("%I:%M:%S %p"),
            'Date': time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"),
            }
        )
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

**P.S:** Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: The order does not matter in storage. You'll fetch that data and order/show it according to your appplication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Amazon DynamoDB is a NoSQL database. **It does not use the concept of columns.** This is because each item (row) can have different data. The management console attempts to show the data in columns to make it easier for us humans to read.

When retrieving data from DynamoDB, you can request specific keys (eg `Name`), or you can receive a JSON object from which you can parse the necessary information based on the Key and Value.